# How to migrate from deprecated Google+ Sign-in API to the new Google Identity platform in a MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, google-signin

A few days ago I was notified via email that Google is deprecating its Google+ APIs:

> On March 7, 2019, all Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in will be shut
>   down completely. This will be a progressive shutdown beginning in late
>   January, with calls to these APIs starting to intermittently fail as
>   early as January 28, 2019.

I currently use Google+ Sign-in as an external login provider in my ASP.NET MVC project. Seemingly, [the ASP.NET documentation has not yet been updated (at the time of writing) to take into account this deprecated API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Is there any guide available on whether or not the `AddGoogle()` extension method can still be used in the `AuthenticationBuilder` middleware, if so, how? If not, where can I find guidance on how to migrate from Google+ to the [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [an open issue on this on the `aspnet\docs` Github page](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/10079).

This seems to be a breaking change, as indicated by the following issues on Github:

- `aspnet\AspNetCore`: [Google+ shutdown will break OAuth provider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6069)
- `aspnet\AspNetKatana`: [Google+ shutdown impacts](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251)

Apparently the Google OAuth provider performs a call to `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me`, which is used to get profile information. As [stated by ThoughtHopper](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6069#issuecomment-449426371), *"[t]he current code works until it tries to retrieve the userinfo."*

A [temporary workaround was posted by Tratcher](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6069#issuecomment-449461197), which is claimed to work for ASP.NET 2.0 and later:

```
.AddGoogle(o =>
        {
            o.ClientId = Configuration["google:clientid"];
            o.ClientSecret = Configuration["google:clientsecret"];
            o.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo";
            o.ClaimActions.Clear();
            o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
            o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
            o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_Name");
            o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_Name");
            o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "profile");
            o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
            o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:image", "picture");
        })
```

This changes the endpoint from which information is retrieved (no longer relying on Google+) and changes the way user info is mapped since this has changed.

From the amount of attention these issues are receiving I expect an update to be pushed out by Microsoft in the near future. Until then, this fix should work with the Google+ API disabled.

Comment: On Jan 8 there was a public announcement on this issue, [officially recommending the fix above for ASP.NET Core 2.x](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6486). For .NET Framework, an update of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` to 4.0.1 should suffice [as outlined in Machado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55286012/590790).

Comment: But, this has now [been incorporated in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` by default](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6486#issuecomment-465297221) starting from v2.2.2. However, [this does not yet seem packaged in the latest build SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) (v2.2.105).

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is .NET Framework only.**

It should already be solved by the Katana project nowdays, so as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285974/4367683):

> Just update the package `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` to version `4.0.1`.
>
> You can read more [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251).
>
> Or see a workaround for .NET Framework 4+ [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251#issuecomment-449587635).

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a dupe. I most likely asked this before this release. I'll try to upgrade soon to verify and will accept after.

Comment: I think the same, before answering here I flagged that question as a dupe, hehe.

Comment: `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` is [not relevant for a .NET Core project, it seems](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6486): "The affected NuGet packages are `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` for ASP.NET Core and `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` for Microsoft.Owin with ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC."

Comment: According to [that announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6486), the recommendation for ASP.NET Core 2.x is still to use the fix I [outlined in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53923875/590790).

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that you're using .NET Core, but this helped me to find the solution for .NET Framework so I shared the solution.

Comment: Oh, and that makes the other question not a dupe!