# How to migrate from Google+ Login to Google Sign In in c# MVC

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, google-plus, owin, google-signin

My web site allows users to register and log in with their Google Account.
My c# MVC app uses the feature the template offered using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.

I have received an email from Google that they are shutting down Google+. The email said to transfer over to Google Sign In.

Any good articles that explain this topic for c# MVC apps using Owin features?
Any pointers where to start would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Michael

Comment: It would help us a lot if you posted your current code to help give you pointers and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the package `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` to version `4.0.1`.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251).

Or see a workaround for .NET Framework 4+ [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251#issuecomment-449587635).